# Interacting with multiple PHP classes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning on PHP classes. I can write a basic PHP classes but having trouble when accessing variables and functions from other classes.
My first class

```
Class First_class
{
  public $options;
  function __construct() 
   { 
      $this->options = get_option('theme_options'); //wordpress fn
   }
  function my_function() {
    add_menu_page(...)
  }
}

Class Second_class
{
 public $first_class_object;
function __construct() 
   { 
      $this->first_class_object = new First_class();
      //Trying to access $this->options here
   }
}

new Second_class();
Class Third_class
{
 public $first_class_object;
function __construct() 
   { 
      $this->first_class_object = new First_class();
      //Trying to access $this->options here
   }
}
 new Third_class();
```

I am trying to access public variables from Class First_class using `$first_class_object = new First_class();` in the second class and third classes. You see when I initiate new First Class in other classes `add_menu_page()` triggers two times. I am not sure how to access the variables and functions properly. May be constructors? 
Sorry may be I am something wrong here?

I am looking for an experts suggestion.

Comment: you should extend class one in the other classes. Did you try that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you try accessing other class Properties, you could use `className::propertyName`

**OR**

if you wanna access properties within the class you can use `self::` or `$this`.

know more about accessing properties and traverses under classes.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: this is something I am trying to do Scope resolution. So to access a static variable from the first class, I need to use `parent::CONST` ?

Comment: yup, if you wanna access a class as parent and its properties, you could use `extends` to make a childClass, and to access the vars you could use `self::` or `parent::` or `className::`

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to access `$options` from the parent class in the second class? Or I can only get static variables in other classes?

Comment: as you have not made the firstClass as parent, so there is no parent child hierarchy build here, so you can use `First_class::options` to access it. when you build a hierarchy between these classes you could just use `self::options` or `parent::options`

Answer (score 1):

Extend your classes.

An example is below using your code as an example. [3v4l demo is here](https://3v4l.org/LVdAg) and [php extends docs are here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php).

```
<?php 

class FirstClass 
{
    public $options;

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $this->options = ['yay']; //get_option('theme_options'); //wordpress fn
    }

    public function myFunction() 
    {
        //
    }
}

class SecondClass extends FirstClass
{

}

class ThirdClass extends FirstClass
{

}

$secondClass = new SecondClass();
var_dump($secondClass->options);

$thirdClass = new ThirdClass();
var_dump($thirdClass->options);
```

Answer (score -1):

try extend class

```
class Third_class extends First_class
{
   public $first_class_object;

   function __construct() 
   { 
      $this->first_class_object = new First_class();
      //Trying to access $this->options here
   }
}
```

or use this construction for access to you class

```
$this->first_class_object->option
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By extending a class function calls from the first class won't repeat? I mean `add_menu_page()` will not trigger multiple times?